# Does high rank difference imply large amounts of non-positive curvature for homogeneous spaces?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$. Consider the homogeneous space $G/H$ with some $G$-invariant metric, and let $\sec$ denote the sectional curvature function associated to this metric.

**Question:** If $\mathrm{rank}(G)-\mathrm{rank}(H)\geq l$, is it true that there is an $l$-dimensional subspace tangent to $G/H$ on which $\sec\leq 0$?

Or perhaps, under what conditions is there an affirmative answer?

Berger proved that if $G/H$ has $\sec>0$, then $\mathrm{rank}(G)-\mathrm{rank}(H)\leq 1$. So the answer to the above question is "yes" if $l=2$.

If $G/H$ is assumed to be *normal homogeneous*, i.e. the metric is induced by a bi-invariant metric on $G$, then sectional curvature is given by
$$\sec(X,Y)=\frac{1}{4}\big|[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]^\mathfrak{m}\big|^2+\big|[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]^\mathfrak{h}\big|^2,$$
where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the orthogonal complement of $\mathfrak{h}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\hat{X},\hat{Y}$ are the lifts of $X,Y$ to $\mathfrak{m}$. Is the answer to the above question also "yes" in this case?

**Edit - Partial answer to last question:** In [a paper by Spatzier and Strake](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02566609), they show that $\mathrm{rank}(G/H)\geq \mathrm{rank}(G)-\mathrm{dim}(H)$ for normal homogeneous spaces.

Comment: Can you explain how the formula for curvature with a normal homogeneous metric answers your question in that particular situation?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Couldn't you take $Z_1,\dots,Z_l$ that are from a maximal abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ and lie in $\mathfrak{m}$, then $\sec\equiv 0$ on the span of their projections to $G/H$?

Comment: You may be able to, but it's not clear to me that $Z_1,..., Z_l$ exist.  If $\mathfrak{t}$ denotes any maximal abelian subalgebra, it seems possible that $\mathfrak{t}\cap \mathfrak{m} = \{0\}$.  Of course, for your argument to work you just need one $\mathfrak{t}$ to have large intersection with $\mathfrak{m}$, but it's not clear to me that this has to happen.

Comment: (Since I now have two comments which don't actually help answer you question at all, let me just mention that I suspect the question is very hard for general invariant metrics on $G/H$.  We don't even have a classification of left invariant metrics on Lie groups with non-negative sectional curvature, except for a low dim examples.  Also, I REALLY like your animation of a Cheeger Deformation!)

Comment: Thank you for the information and compliment Jason. In light of what you said, I’ll edit the part of my question that addresses normal homogeneous spaces. I think that partial answers to my main question can possibly come about from working with the formalism used by Ziller and his collaborators for homogeneous metrics, e.g. the “Revisiting Homogeneous Spaces” paper with Wilking. I’m just new to a lot of the algebraic techniques that are involved.